# Answer moved to comment?

Tags: discussion

Maybe this is a bit quibbling, but I'm curious why my answer was changed to a comment on [this](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1823/jesus-predicts-that-some-will-not-die-until-he-comes-again-in-his-kingdom-but-th) question?   I did use the previous person's answer as a bit of a springboard, but my answer (John was given a vision of the kindgom of God prior to his death) seemed to be quite different than the other user's (John may still be alive somewhere and could be until Christ's return).

As a meta-meta aside, maybe: Is this the proper way to ask these kind of things?

Comment: Believe it or not, we moderators did NOT coordinate our answers.

Comment: As for your meta-meta.  The best answer is to bring it up in chat.  However, we realize that not everyone can do that, so posting something here is sufficient.

Answer (score 5):

In reviewing the other mod's actions, I would suggest that there are two reasons to convert that to a comment.

First, it wasn't an answer to the OP's question. Using a question as a springboard for some other topic is not how SE works.

Secondly, it isn't valid to answer questions with other questions. That's something to do as a comment to clarify the original question or (if a significantly different topic) as a new question.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, the "answer" part of your answer didn't really say much of anything *and* it referred to a different answer, giving it the feel of a comment. It would have been better if you had elaborated on what you meant.

Second, it ended with a question. This is not a philosophical forum where you can answer questions with more questions. That question would have been fine as its own question and not tacked on to the end of an answer.

<sup>Having said that, a site where you can nest questions sounds interesting... :P</sup>

Comment: Wouldn't that be a meta site?  :P

Comment: After re-reading my answer, I see that you're right that the first part of my answer didn't say much.   I was trying to be friendly, but I think it didn't contribute anything to the topic.   I think it also led to some ambiguity and confusion regarding the second part of my post, which was directed as an intended answer to the original question (rather than a question to the person to whom the first part of my post was directed.)   I think I see the confusion now.   Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

From the [faq](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/faq#deletion):

> Answers that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed
>   * commentary on the question or other answers
>   * asking another, different question
>   * “thanks!” or “me too!” responses
>   * exact duplicates of other answers
>   * barely more than a link to an external site
>   * not even a partial answer to the actual question

In this particular case, the answer contained two sentences.  The first was a commentary on another answer.  The second sentence introduced another question.

Neither of these sentences could stand on their own as a sufficient answer, therefore this post is considered "low quality".

The purpose of a QnA site is to ask and answer questions.  Your post did neither so it was removed.  The moderator who removed it felt that it had enough merit to remain part of the site and so he (generously) converted it to a comment.

Comment: I really did intend my "answer" as an answer to the question.   Basically, as I read it, the question was "How does one resolve the fact that this didn't seem to happen as Jesus suggested it would?"  and I suggested an answer (albeit a timid and speculative one) that offered, what I thought, was a possible resolution to the question asked.   Perhaps I shouldn't have phrased it as a question; I can see how that undermines the nature of an answer.   I can respect different interpretations, though, and the rules of the site, so this gives me what I'm looking for.  Thanks.

Comment: @Steven When You begin your sentence with "This gets props", that makes it sound more like a compliment rather than a resolution to a question.  Furthermore, adding a question after a compliment doesn't strengthen the argument that this was meant as an answer.  **If you want to edit your answer to be more appropriate as an answer, we can undelete it.**  [This meta post may help you in writing an appropriate answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7656/how-do-i-write-a-good-answer-to-a-question).